# Dest to Source: Does Path Exist?

Tags: java, path, grid, src

What is wrong with this code? It attempts to mark visited coordinates as 1 so that they are not revisited, and then adds or subtracts one from the horizontal or vertical destination points and repeats the process.

```
public static boolean pathExists(int destX,
        int destY, int sourceX, int sourceY) {
    if (sourceY == destY && sourceX == destX) {
        return true;
    }

if ((coordinates[destX][destY] == 0) && isMoveableTo(destX, destY)) {

                coordinates[destX][destY] = 1;          
                return ((pathExists(destX + 1, destY, sourceX, sourceY) && isMoveableTo(destX + 1, destY))
                        || (pathExists(destX, destY + 1, sourceX, sourceY) && isMoveableTo(destX, destY + 1))
                        || (pathExists(destX - 1, destY, sourceX, sourceY) && isMoveableTo(destX - 1, destY))
                        || (pathExists(destX, destY - 1, sourceX, sourceY) && isMoveableTo(destX, destY - 1))); 
}
return false;
}
```

The problem lies somewhere in the fact that it can both subtract 1 from destX AND subtract 1 from destY at the same time(?), attempting to move diagonally, which it shouldn't be able to.

Thank you.

Comment: *This* code doesn't subtract 1 from both destX and destY, so the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: It seems the problem is elsewhere, btw the bitwise and operator in the last conditionis a typo?

Comment: Yes. It is fixed now, but I have the same problem. Will do more digging into the rest of the code.

Comment: Got it. Had to remove the isMoveableTo's at the bottom.